# What does the bill status of "Held at the desk" mean?

Tags: united-states, congress, terminology

Earlier this year, the Senate passed S. 1867, the **[COVID-19 Origin Act of 2021](https://www.congress.gov/117/bills/s1867/BILLS-117s1867cps.pdf)** by unanimous consent.   This appears to be a "Sense of Congress" resolution, and calls for declassification of intelligence related to the causes of COVID-19 (but allows for redactions to protect intelligence sources and methods.)

According to the congressional website, [the bill remains "Held at the desk"](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/senate-bill/1867/all-actions-without-amendments) in the house.   What does this mean?

I've seen reports that [house democrats recently blocked this bill by a vote of 216 to 207](https://townhall.com/tipsheet/spencerbrown/2021/07/21/house-democrats-block-covid-origins-bill-n2592839).   Why hasn't this vote been reflected in the bill's status, and in the national press?   Has this report (from townhall.com) distorted the facts about the COVID-19 Origin Act?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *U.S. House: What does the bill the status of “Held at the desk” mean?*

> **[Hold the bill at the desk](http://www.lexisnexis.com/help/cu/glossary/glossary.htm#Hearings1)**
>
> A maneuver reserving the right of action on a measure to the full Chamber, rather than to a committee. A bill held at the desk is available for immediate consideration. Since it is not referred to a committee, the bill has no hearings or committee reports accompanying it from that Chamber. A bill passed by one Chamber and referred to the second Chamber often is held at the desk in the second Chamber, particularly when the second Chamber already is working on similar legislation.

In this case, the House was already working on an earlier bill, [H.R.3191 - COVID–19 Origin Act of 2021](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/3191/all-actions), with the same title.

---

> *Has this report (from townhall.com) distorted the facts about the COVID-19 Origin Act?*

From the *[Congressional Record](https://www.congress.gov/117/crec/2021/07/20/167/127/CREC-2021-07-20-pt1-PgH3708.pdf#page=3)* for July 20, 2021, during consideration of [H.Res. 535](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-resolution/535) - Providing for consideration of ..., Rep. Burgess stated "if we defeat the previous question, I will offer an amendment to the rule to immediately consider S. 1867, the COVID–19 Origin Act, ...." The previous question was not defeated, having passed 216-207, thus the amendment which would have forced a vote on S. 1867 was not offered, so there was no vote on S. 1867.

Any distortion would be related to an implication that the Senate bill, S. 1867, was defeated rather than just the amendment to H.Res. 535 for consideration of the bill. Thus, the statement,

> Rep. Michael Burgess (R-TX) brought the COVID-19 Origin Act to the House floor for consideration with Reps. Brad Wenstrup (R-OH) and Darin LaHood (R-IL) explaining its importance shortly before Democrats voted down the measure Tuesday night. [townhall.com](https://townhall.com/tipsheet/spencerbrown/2021/07/21/house-democrats-block-covid-origins-bill-n2592839)

appears to be a misstatement of what happened.

This action was also reported in *[The Federalist](https://thefederalist.com/2021/07/21/house-democrats-block-bill-declassifying-the-origins-of-covid-19/)*, July 21, 2021.

> The COVID-19 Origin Act was brought to the floor by Representatives Burgess (R-TX), LaHood (R-IL), and Wenstrup (R-OH) before it was shot down in a 216 to 207 vote.

This is another distortion of what happened.

In fact, Republicans offered Democrats the opportunity to vote on the Senate COVID-19 Origin Act. Democrats rejected the offer. Nothing changed with respect to S. 1867, it is still "held at the desk" and could be brought up again.

---

> *Why hasn't this vote been reflected in the bill's status, and in the national press?*

As [Joe W](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/66568/26455) mentions, "why it is not updated ... could be a simple matter of the site not being updated in real time [and] might take a day or two to update."

The national press (or mainstream media) likely did not report the story because there was nothing of significance to report.

Comment: HR 3191-2021 has identical text.

Answer (score -4):

It means that there are differences in the version that the house and senate has passed and there will need to be further work on it. As for why it is not updated it could be a simple matter of the site not being updated in real time might take a day or two to update.

As a side note when I have been searching for information on that bill I only see a single website reporting that it was voted on and blocked.

https://www.govinfo.gov/help/bills

> An alternate name for this bill version is Ordered Held at House Desk after being Received from House. This version has been held at the desk in the House.

> An alternate name for this bill version is Ordered Held at Senate Desk after being Received from House. This version is a bill or resolution as received in the Senate from the House which has been ordered to be held at the desk, sometimes in preparation for going to conference. It is available to be called up for consideration by unanimous consent.

Comment: H.R.3191 and S. 1867 are identical in terms of the text.

Comment: @Burt_Harris Do you have something that shows that?

Comment: https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/3191/all-info?r=134&s=1 listed them as identical

Comment: @Burt_Harris S. 1867 is listed as a related bill while S. 1348 is listed as an identical bill. The link you have in your question also lists them as related bills and not identical bills.  Nothing I see lists S. 1867 as an identical bill. It shows you have two different bills with the same title coming from the senate and at least one in the house with that title

Comment: Joe, your answer said "there are differences in the version that the house and senate has passed".   What related bill has the house passed, & where can I find the text?

Comment: The differences between S.1348 and S.1867 are editorial and minimal, as can be seen at https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/117/s1867/text#compare=es

Comment: @Burt_Harris the point is you claimed that they are identical when they are not. Even if they are just editorial they still have to go through reconciliation in order to make sure the language in both chambers matches up. Now that might not be a lot of work if they are just minimal but it still has to be done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127779/discussion-between-burt-harris-and-joe-w).